# Trick question to show integral is positive

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $\varphi$ be an odd and increasing function, show for any $h\in\mathbb{R}$
$$
h \int_{-\infty}^\infty \varphi(y) \varphi^{\prime}(y) \exp \left(-y^{2}+2 h y-h^{2}\right) \mathrm{d} y \geq 0.
$$

My attempt: $\exp \left(-y^{2}+2 h y-h^{2}\right)\varphi^{\prime}(y)\ge0$ inside the integrand. But I have no way to deal with $h\varphi(y)$ part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $h\gt 0$, exp term is larger for $y\gt 0$, so integral $\int\limits_0^{\infty}$ is greater than other half, using $\phi (y)$ odd.
Similarly for $h\lt 0$, same logic applies in reverse with integral $\int\limits_{-\infty}^0$ is greater than other half, using $h\phi (y)\gt 0$ for $y\lt 0$.